Google indexing and htaccess redirects
My website uses two pages to generate nearly all the content.
I have fixed the complaints Google had with browser URL rewrites and canonical references only to have it choke on redirect.
I use htaccess to convert the desired public-facing url (say www.mysite.com/ThisIsPage1) to the page that generates the actual viewable page (say www.mysite.com/genpage?word=ThisIsPage1).
I tried adding a 302 redirect in the htaccess file, but Google did not think much of that.
What is the right incantation to make Google index /ThisIsPage1 and not worry about how I handle the page rendering?

to fix the issue remove the [R] flag from your .htaccess file to avoid a front-end redirect. instead, use [L] which ensures the URL rewrite happens behind the scenes without confusing google. this way, google will index /ThisISPage1 without worrying about how the page is generated.

If you want Google to index and show /ThisIsPage1 in its search results, it must directly return its content without a redirect.
You should be able to map those nice URLs to the genpage URL in the .htaccess file, in a way that does not do an external redirect. e.g.
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ /genpage?word==$1 [L]


Thanks.
We have been using RewriteRule from the start. That's how we guide the source URI to the URI that generates the page.
The only difference is that we used [R,NC]. Why would [L] be a better alternative in terms of Google accepting the URI hand-off and adding the originating URI to their index?

R makes it a front-end redirect. Without it, there is no redirect, which is what you want. L means last and stops the system from trying to process any more commands.
